# Recorrer array JSON y rellenar <select> dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy intentando rellenar un `<select>` a partir de los datos almacenados en un array JSON. Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
applications = {
  "apps": [
    { "app":"app_uno", "buzon":"buzon_uno" },
    { "app":"app_dos", "buzon":"buzón_dos" }
  ]
};

function fillSelector(options_list) { 
  var options = options_list; 
  var modelList = document.getElementById("select_form"); 
  for (var i in options.apps) { 
    var opt = options.apps[i].app; 
    modelList.options.add(opt);
  }
} 

fillSelector(applications);
```

```html
<select id="select_form">
  <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
<select>
```

En este ejemplo tendría que almacenar en "opt" los valores "uno", "dos", etc.
No sé dónde está el problema ya que nunca he utilizado JSON, esta vez es la primera que lo uso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no lo estás teniendo al recorrer JSON, que es correcto. El problema es al añadir la opción al `select` porque con `select.options.add` se espera que lo que estés pasando sea un elemento de tipo `option` pero estás pasando un objeto que no lo es.

Para solucionar eso, podrías crear un `option` y pasárselo al `add`. Aquí dejo tu código con los cambios comentados:

```js
applications = {
  "apps": [
    { "app":"app_uno", "buzon":"buzon_uno" },
    { "app":"app_dos", "buzon":"buzón_dos" }
  ]
};

function fillSelector(options_list) { 
  var options = options_list; 
  var modelList = document.getElementById("select_form"); 
  for (var i in options.apps) { 
    // creamos un elemento de tipo option
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    // le damos un valor
    opt.value = options.apps[i].app;
    // le ponemos un texto
    opt.textContent = options.apps[i].buzon;
    // lo agregamos al select
    modelList.options.add(opt);
  }
} 

fillSelector(applications);
```

```html
<select id="select_form">
  <option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>
<select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alvaro!